# React Native: How to implement 2 columns of swipping cards?

Tags: react-native, swipe, card

I am trying to implement a scrollable list of cards in 2 columns. The cards should be swipe-able left or right out of the screen to be removed.

Basically, it should be like how the Chrome app is showing the list of tabs currently, which can be swiped away to be closed. See example image [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/6161666/android-chrome-tabs-used-to-be-stacked-now-they-are-displayed-in-mini-square-blocks-how-to-reverse?hl=en).

I am able to implement the list of cards in 2 columns using FlatList. However, I have trouble making the cards swipe-able. I tried react-tinder-card but it cannot restrict swiping up and down and hence the list becomes not scrollable. react-native-deck-swiper also does not work well with list.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to implement a component that satisfies the following requirements:

1. Create a two column `FlatList` whose items are your cards.
2. Implement a gesture handling that recognizes `swipeLeft` and `swipeRight` actions which will remove the card that was swiped.
3. The `swipe` actions should be animated, meaning we have some kind of `drag of the screen` behavior.

I will use the basic react-native `FlatList` with `numColumns={2}` and [react-native-swipe-list-view](https://github.com/jemise111/react-native-swipe-list-view) to handle `swipeLeft`and `swipeRight` actions as well as the desired animations.

I will implement a `fire and forget` action, thus after removing an item, it is gone forever. We will implement a `restore mechanism` later if we want to be able to restore removed items.

My initial implementation works as follows:

1. Create a `FlatList` with `numColumns={2}` and some additional dummy styling to add some margins.
2. Create state using `useState` which holds an array of objects that represent our cards.
3. Implement a function that removes an item from the state provided an id.
4. Wrap the item to be rendered in a `SwipeRow`.
5. Pass the `removeItem` function to the `swipeGestureEnded` prop.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react"
import { FlatList, SafeAreaView, Text, View } from "react-native"
import { SwipeRow } from "react-native-swipe-list-view"

const data = [
  {
    id: "0",
    title: "Title 1",
  },
  {
    id: "1",
    title: "Title 2",
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    title: "Title 3",
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    title: "Title 4",
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    title: "Title 5",
  },
  {
    id: "5",
    title: "Title 6",
  },
  {
    id: "6",
    title: "Title 7",
  },
  {
    id: "7",
    title: "Title 8",
  },
]

export function Test() {
  const [cards, setCards] = useState(data)
  const [removed, setRemoved] = useState([])

  function removeItem(id) {
    let previous = [...cards]
    let itemToRemove = previous.find((x) => x.id === id)
    setCards(previous.filter((c) => c.id !== id))
    setRemoved([...removed, itemToRemove])
  }

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ margin: 20 }}>
      <FlatList
        data={cards}
        numColumns={2}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        renderItem={({ index, item }) => (
          <SwipeRow swipeGestureEnded={() => removeItem(item.id)}>
            <View />
            <View style={{ margin: 20, borderWidth: 1, padding: 20 }}>
              <Text>{item.title}</Text>
            </View>
          </SwipeRow>
        )}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}
```

Notice that we need some kind of property in our objects in order to determine which one we want to remove. I have used a basic `id` property here, which is quite common using `FlatList`. If you are retrieving your data from an `API` which does not provide the same `id`, then we could just do some preprocessing (`normalization`) first and add the `id` prop ourselves.

The initial view looks as follows.

[image]

Swiping, let's say the item with 'Title 6' to the right or to the left removes it.

It might be desired to implement the following feature as well.

- If the item is in the first column, then only swiping to the left will remove the item.
- If the item is in the second column, then only swiping to the right will remove the item.

This is easily implemented using the `index` param which is passed to the `renderItem` function and the `vx` prop of the `gestureState` passed to the `swipeGestureEnded` function.

Here is fully working implementation.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react"
import { FlatList, SafeAreaView, Text, View } from "react-native"
import { SwipeRow } from "react-native-swipe-list-view"

const data = [
  {
    id: "0",
    title: "Title 1",
  },
  {
    id: "1",
    title: "Title 2",
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    title: "Title 3",
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    title: "Title 4",
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    title: "Title 5",
  },
  {
    id: "5",
    title: "Title 6",
  },
  {
    id: "6",
    title: "Title 7",
  },
  {
    id: "7",
    title: "Title 8",
  },
]

export function Test() {
  const [cards, setCards] = useState(data)
  const [removed, setRemoved] = useState([])

  function removeItem(id) {
    let previous = [...cards]
    let itemToRemove = previous.find((x) => x.id === id)
    setCards(previous.filter((c) => c.id !== id))
    setRemoved([...removed, itemToRemove])
  }

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ margin: 20 }}>
      <FlatList
        data={cards}
        numColumns={2}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        renderItem={({ index, item }) => (
          <SwipeRow
            swipeGestureEnded={(key, event) => {
              if (event.gestureState.vx < 0) {
                if (index % 2 === 0) {
                  removeItem(item.id)
                }
              } else if (event.gestureState.vx >= 0) {
                if (index % 2 === 1) {
                  removeItem(item.id)
                }
              }
            }}
            disableLeftSwipe={index % 2 === 1}
            disableRightSwipe={index % 2 === 0}>
            <View />
            <View style={{ margin: 20, borderWidth: 1, padding: 20 }}>
              <Text>{item.title}</Text>
            </View>
          </SwipeRow>
        )}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}
```

Since the index is zero based in a `FlatList`, an item is in the second column if and only if `index % 2 === 1` (e.g. an item with index `3` is always in the second column and thus not divisible by `2`), on the other hand an item is in the first column if and only if `index % 2 === 0` that is `index` is divisible by `2`.

There are several callback function props in the `SwipeRowComponent` that should be fired in certain situations. However, most of them did not work in my setup and I still have no clue why. I got it to work by using the `event.gestureState.vx` property which is negative if we swipe to the left and positive (including zero) if we swipe to the right.

It might be desired to implement an `undo` button as it is quite common in this kind of functionalities. This can be done as follows:

- Implement a second state which represents a `Queue` that holds lastly removed items. The `undo` button then just `pops` the lastly removed item.

Here is a fully working implementation with a dummy `undo` button that achieves exactly that.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react"
import { Button, FlatList, SafeAreaView, Text, View } from "react-native"
import { SwipeRow } from "react-native-swipe-list-view"

const data = [
  {
    id: "0",
    title: "Title 1",
  },
  {
    id: "1",
    title: "Title 2",
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    title: "Title 3",
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    title: "Title 4",
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    title: "Title 5",
  },
  {
    id: "5",
    title: "Title 6",
  },
  {
    id: "6",
    title: "Title 7",
  },
  {
    id: "7",
    title: "Title 8",
  },
]

export function Test() {
  const [cards, setCards] = useState(data)
  const [removed, setRemoved] = useState([])

  function removeItem(id) {
    let previous = [...cards]
    let itemToRemove = previous.find((x) => x.id === id)
    setCards(previous.filter((c) => c.id !== id))
    setRemoved([...removed, itemToRemove])
  }

  function undoRemove() {
    if (removed && removed.length > 0) {
      let itemToUndo = removed[removed.length - 1]
      setCards([...cards, itemToUndo])
      setRemoved(removed.filter((c) => c.id !== itemToUndo.id))
    }
  }

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ margin: 20 }}>
      <FlatList
        data={cards}
        numColumns={2}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        renderItem={({ index, item }) => (
          <SwipeRow
            swipeGestureEnded={(key, event) => {
              if (event.gestureState.vx < 0) {
                if (index % 2 === 0) {
                  removeItem(item.id)
                }
              } else if (event.gestureState.vx >= 0) {
                if (index % 2 === 1) {
                  removeItem(item.id)
                }
              }
            }}
            disableLeftSwipe={index % 2 === 1}
            disableRightSwipe={index % 2 === 0}>
            <View />
            <View style={{ margin: 20, borderWidth: 1, padding: 20 }}>
              <Text>{item.title}</Text>
            </View>
          </SwipeRow>
        )}
      />
      <Button onPress={undoRemove} title="Undo" />
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}
```

Notice that my `undo` button just appends the removed item to the end of the list. If you want to keep the initial index, then you need to save the old index and push the item to the correct position.

Here is workin [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@pgrepds/swipeable-list-item) of my last implementation.